# How to remove this repeated call to `ack`

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash and I am writing a shell script that goes through the listed dependencies in package.json (`jq`), sees how many times it's used (`ack`), and if it's less than 2 times, echo that.

```
arr=( $(jq -r '.dependencies | keys | .[]'  package.json) )

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    n=$(ack $i --ignore-dir=dist --ignore-file='match:/checkDependencies.sh|package.json/' | wc -l)
    if [[ $n -le 2 ]]; then
        echo "Package $i has too few occurences"
        ack $i --ignore-dir=dist --ignore-file='match:/checkDependencies.sh|package.json/'
        echo
    fi
done
```

You can see that I `ack` twice. How can I just `ack` once? I tried setting the output to a variable but it's not working how I want it to.

output from john1024's answer:

```
bash -x checkDependencies.sh
+ arr=($(jq -r '.devDependencies | keys | .[]'  package.json))
++ jq -r '.devDependencies | keys | .[]' package.json
checkDependencies.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `s=$(ack "$i" --ignore-dir=dist --ignore-file='match:/package.json/')'
checkDependencies.sh: line 4: ` s=$(ack "$i" --ignore-dir=dist --ignore-file='match:/package.json/')'
```

provided solution (now with the `do` added)

```
arr=( $(jq -r '.devDependencies | keys | .[]'  package.json) )

for i in "${arr[@]}"
    do
    s=$(ack "$i" --ignore-dir=dist --ignore-file='match:/package.json/')
    if [ "$(wc -l <<<"$s")" -le 2 ]; then
        echo "Package $i has too few occurences"
        echo "$s"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ack only once, try:

```
arr=( $(jq -r '.dependencies | keys | .[]'  package.json) )

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    s=$(ack "$i" --ignore-dir=dist --ignore-file='match:/checkDependencies.sh|package.json/')
    if [ "$(wc -l <<<"$s")" -le 2 ]; then
        echo "Package $i has too few occurences"
        echo "$s"
    fi
done
```

Here, for each package, we store ack's output in variable `s` and then use `s` wherever the output of ack is needed.

Comment: Don't put double quotes around the invocation of `wc`. It prints the output with leading spaces, so you need to ignore them.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting observation.  I just tested it and I see no ill effects of leading spaces.  Are you aware of circumstances under which leading spaces confuse bash's arithmetic comparison?

Comment: getting this: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `s=$(ack "$i" --ignore-dir=dist --ignore-file='match:/package.json/')'

Comment: @swagrov Hmm. I can't reproduce that.  Would you run `bash -x yourscript.sh` and copy-and-paste the output into your question?  (Comments lack adequate formatting.  Don't put it in a comment.  Paste it onto the end of the question.)

Comment: @John1024 ok i edited my question. dont worry that i changed a filename

Comment: @swagrov Thanks.  My guess is that the cause is unbalanced quotes somewhere.  Please add to the question a copy of your version of my answer.

Comment: @John1024 okay its up

Comment: @swagrov Ugh! I forgot to put the `do` after the `for` statement.  My fault!  Answer corrected.

Comment: @John1024 haha well we both missed that one :P

Comment: @John1024 I'm pretty sure I've run into problems due to those leading spaces in the past, but it may have been in some other context, such as substituting into another string. Both `[[` and `[` appear to trim whitespace when doing numeric comparisons.

Comment: @Barmar Bash does have quirks.  An analogous problem that I know I have run into is leading zeros:  `8` is eight but `08` is an error.